# If statement acting differently based on data type of variable used in condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--) {
    int x;
    int y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    if (x % 5 == 0 && x <= y) {
      cout << y - x - 0.50 << "wow"
           << "\n";

    } else {
      cout << y << "\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
30 120.00
42 120.00
300 120.00
```

Output:(When y is int)

```
89.5wow
119.5wow
119.5wow
```

Here even though the second and third case should give false and run **else** its instead running **if** itself and not only that x is not being subtracted. This error is solved by making y float. But whats the underlying issue?

Output:(When y is float)

```
89.5wow
120
120
```

Comment: because 120.00 is not an int

Comment: Print `x` and `y` after reading them. Verify that reading succeeded.

Comment: When inputted wouldnt y just become 120? Are there other issues that occur due to that?

Comment: (OT: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: @Joelcantcode It does the first time, and after that the input stream is `.00\n42 120.00\n...`.

Comment: I added a cout<<x<<y<<endl; soon after the cin>>x>>y; and got the same values but 120.00 becomes 120.

Comment: wow ya it fixed. Why does it do that?

Comment: I'm also a big fan of putting parenthesis everywhere to explicitly force an order of operations.  This "(x % 5 == 0 && x <= y)" might be better expressed as "(((x%5) == 0) && (x <= y))"

Answer (score 6):

When you ask `cin` to read an `int`, the `.` is not part of an int so it does not read the `.`

That means the next `cin>>x` starts from the `.` which cannot be part of an int so it still doesn't read it. Same for `y`.

If you'd checked [`cin.fail()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) to see whether something failed, it would tell you that it had. It wasn't able to read any `int` because all it saw was a `.`

`x` and `y` are uninitialized the second and third times around the loop.

When you read `float`s then `.` is allowed to be part of reading a `float` so it continues reading.